# Trigger .onclick() on hover over another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-hover

I'm trying to trigger an .onclick() event when I hover over another div.

The element that needs to trigger the .onclick() event has the ID `#exp_des_p_trig`.

[image: See Console].

The element that needs to be triggered has the href value `#exp_des_p` in an **a tag**.

[image: See console].

I can understand the basics/read JS but I can't write it (yet), I'm thinking something like this:

```
<script>
jQuery('#exp_des_p_trig').hover();
    jQuery('#exp_des_p').onclick();
</script>
```

Can anyone help me correct this so that it works?

**UPDATE:**

I emailed Visual Composer support about this and this is the response I got:

*Instead of triggering a click event you can try attaching vc_active class to the tour vc_tta-tab and vc_tta-panel via js. The vc_active class is responsible for opening a tour content for display.*

Thank you for the answers below, **it seems that this is a Visual Composer related issue** which I will address elsewhere.

Comment: Check out my answer,and check your selectors!`jQuery('#exp_des_p')` this selectors means:select an element with attribute `id` with value `exp_des_p`.Check [this](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

Comment: @JanCiołek hey thanks, I've got a bit of response from the elements now, basically hovering over the trigger element now shows a browser notification which means the top part is working, but the hover trigger isn't - this is the code I'm using: https://jsfiddle.net/rzkrto1o/ - do you know where my issue is?

Comment: Check your selector i bet it miss something.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [trigger method](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

```js
var red = $('#clickAbleElement').click(function(){
  alert('You have clicked on red');
})

var green = $('#hoverMe').hover(function(){
  red.trigger('click');
})
```

```css
#clickAbleElement {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:red;
}

#hoverMe {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="clickAbleElement">Click Me</div>
<div id="hoverMe">Hover Me</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you only need the event for the mouse entering the element, you can use the mouseenter event, and then target the element with the given href and trigger a click

```js
$('#exp_des_p_trig').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $('[href="#exp_des_p"]').trigger('click');
});

$('[href="#exp_des_p"]').on('click', function() {
    console.log('works fine !')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="exp_des_p_trig">Hover me !</div>
<a href="#exp_des_p"></a>
```

Note that triggering a click on an anchor doesn't redirect, it just triggers any event handlers attached.

Comment: thanks, this doesn't seem to be working unfortunately, is there anything else I could be missing?

Answer (score 0):

this is a solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#divhover').hover(function (event){
    alert("divhover_hover");  
    $("#aClick").trigger( "click" );
  });

  $('#aClick').on('click',function(event){
    alert("aClick_click");  
  });

})
```

Comment: you can sostitude a selctor wich what do you necessery like to @adeneo post